# Disable code from auto generated edit button in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I've got a Gridview with an auto generated edit linkbutton. Now whenever i click on Edit, the selected gridview row goes in Edit mode. I do not want this since i've written my own code in the RowEditing event.
How can i fix this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method will run after the edit button is pressed, but before the Grid goes into edit mode. So you can run your logic and then cancel the event, the grid will stay in the mode it was when the user clicked the button.

Like this:

```
// your logic
e.Cancel = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

[How to: Enable Default Editing in the GridView Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czzytf25%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
<asp:GridView Runat="server" ID="GridView1" 
  AutoGenerateEditButton="false" />
```

Comment: I don't think this is the answer to his question, but a better solution to his problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write in 'Row Editing' event

```
e.NewEditIndex = -1
```

So, the row will not go in edit mode